# Extra height on wrapper when img is not a block element?

Tags: html, css

I thought I understood how inline and block elements work, however this has thrown me. I have found a fix for the issue however **I have no idea why it works**.

For some reason if you have an `img` inside a `div`, the div is like `3.5px` taller than the image. However if you set the image as a block element this extra height disappears.

Basic HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.basini.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/seeing-in-the-dark.jpg" width="300" height="230"  />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background: orange;
}
#wrapper img {
    /* display: block; this will remove the extra height */
}
```

I have set up a [jsfiddle to demonstrate the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/kQS34/1/)

**Why does this happen and why does making the 'img' a block element fix it? Are there any other solutions?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, an image is rendered inline, like a letter.

It sits on the same line that a, b, c and d sit on.

There is space below that line for the descenders you find on letters like j, p and q.

You can adjust the vertical-align of the image to position it elsewhere.

Comment: You can also set the line-height of the div containing the image to 0 to remove below space, but this is not good if the div contains multiple line text as well

Answer (score 3):

It's due to the `line-height` of the wrapping `div` of the `img` tag.

To fix it, you can set `line-height:0` to the div, `float` the img or `display:block` the img.

Better explained: [How to control line height in <p> styled as inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001891/how-to-control-line-height-in-p-styled-as-inline)

Comment: Thanks, don't really want to set the line-height to 0 because I actually have text in that wrapper too. And I guess floating the image works because a floated element also becomes a block element. Good to know though +1

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to [reset all styles](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)? before applying new styles?