# Navigation bar, visible spaces between list items

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

I have a traditional nav created. between each li I put one div with 1px width and slightly smaller height than nav bar.

Basically I was going for this look:

http://subalee.com/nav.jpg

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <div></div>
    <li><a href="#">Domov</a></li>
    <div></div>
    <li><a href="#">Služby</a></li>
    <div></div>
    <li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>
    <div></div>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <div></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul div {
    height:31px;
    width:1px;
    background-color:#34b9ff;
    display:inline-block;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
```

When I change div to display:inline; text works properly but those visible spaces somehow dissapear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does the space around img elements originate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380670/where-does-the-space-around-img-elements-originate)

Comment: From the accepted answer in the duplicate marked above - it is due to the whitespace in your html between your `inline` and `inline-block` elements. Also note that your HTML is invalid as you shouldn't have the `div` elements directly insde the `ul` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1:
You are not allowed to place ANYTHING else into a `ul` except `li`.
I'd consider another approach to skip the syntactically useless styling-divs:

[JS-Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2uHXJ/3/)

```
nav ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
    display:inline;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

You can avoid spaces between inline elements by setting `font-size` to 0 and resetting it on the `li`.

Comment: Yeah that was my second option, however those borders in your example will be the same height as the li elemnt and i wanted them slightly longer, but anyway i think i'm gonna use  your example, thanks :)

Comment: Oh that's easily done! Just add some padding to your list-item. See my updated Fiddle. When your question has been answered, you should accept the answer that helped you most. Otherwise less and less people will try to help you :)

Comment: Thanks, kinda new to stackexchange site :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a DIV within UL.
I'm sure you could achieve the same results with LIs only, by adding the appropriate style.

Comment: Having a `div` in an `ul` isn't HTML5 compliant, which states a UL should contain 0 or more list items. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want any change in the way the elements are declared in your html then 
use

```
border-left:1px solid #34b9ff;
```

instead of `background-color:`
and use `display:inline;`

Full css would look like

```
nav ul div {
    height:31px;
    width:1px;
    border-left:1px solid #34b9ff;
    display:inline;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPSUn/)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in these cases is that you can't have ANY whitespace between `li`'s as this will show up.

Following jsFiddle show exactly your code with space removed results in what I think is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/jPF2p/

Comment: Well that's exactly the problem i have, the li gets pushed down :/ Anyway i didn't know that i can't have anything between li, so thanks for pointing that out :)