# Unwanted space between table rows/cells, for the 532nd time

Tags: html, css

Tables beat me again.

I have a very simple one here:

```
<table style="width: 200px; margin: 20px auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: none;">
  <tr style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <td style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <img src="http://breadedcat.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cat-breading-tutorial-004.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: grey; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <td style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">Hehehehehehe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/ohys4x2o/**

I think I already added too much of styles like `border: none; padding: 0;` and so on to the code - yet still **there's an unwanted space** between the row with the cat and the grey one with "Hehehe" text.

Table gurus welcome. Please, help. Please. Those tables.. they.. kill me...

Answer (score 2):

Set the vertical alignment on the image to top:

```
img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1tLn94q2/)**

By default it's set to baseline and reserves space for descender text elements (e.g. g, y, j)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the image, not the table.  Similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380670/where-does-the-space-around-img-elements-originate), the image is including the extra pixels because it is an "inline-block" element.  If you add "display:block" to the image it will remove the space.

Comment: Thanks, valid solution as well.