# Inline elements do not wrap to baseline grid

Tags: css, typography

I cannot get the text inside my `<header>` to align to a baseline grid when the text wraps.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>Sample Title</h1>
    <p class="tag">#Tag</p>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    display: block;
    }

h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0 24px 0 0;
    }

p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0 24px 0 0;
    }
```

[Good] Text without wrapping
[image: Text without wrapping]

[Bad] Text does not align to grid when it wraps between `<h1>` and `<p>`
[image]

[Good] Text aligns to grid when it wraps through `<h1>`
[image: Text wraps properly when line breaks across <h1>]

I followed @[sled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440764/sled)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001891/how-to-control-line-height-in-p-styled-as-inline#answers) to set `line-height: 0` on `<header>`, but that gave me the opposite problem:

[Good] Text aligns to grid when it wraps between `<h1>` and `<p>`
[image]

[Bad] Text does not align to grid when it wraps through `<h1>`
[image]

Comment: When `line-height: 0` is set on `<header>` Firefox increases the height of `<h1>`.  When `<h1>` wraps, Firefox calculates `<h1>`'s height as 77px instead of 72px.

Comment: @sled's suggestion also said to float the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements.  Unfortunately, floating `<h1>` and `<p>` pushes `<p>` to a new line when `<h1>` wraps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `vertical-align` on `<p>` to  `bottom`. Setting `line-height` on `<header>` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment defaults to baseline, but takes it's "typography" characteristics from it's parent. `<header>` has nothing to pass on to it's children so they're left to default values.  But since your looking for your `#tag` element to adjust with your `<h1>` element, try this:

First, change your `<p>` to a `<span>`, you can just as easily turn a `<span>` into an inline-block as a `<p>` and not have to then correct for all the margin and padding (cleaner CSS).

Then place the `<span>` within the `<h1>` tag

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <h1>Sample Title
        <span class="tag">#Tag</span>
    </h1>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    line-height: 36px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin: 0 24px 0 0;
}
span {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but it introduces a new problem.  I used the right margins on `<h1>` and `<p>` to put a 24px space between the two elements when they were on the same line.  Since the space was a right margin, it wouldn't introduce an awkward indent when the wrap would occur between `<h1>` and `<p>`.  Now that `<p>` is inside of `<h1>`, I can't use that right margin.

Comment: Also, you're solution obscures the semantic meaning of my HTML.

Comment: so change the span in the above to an `inline-block` and add a 24px left margin

Comment: The left margin IS the problem.

Comment: Originally you asked how to make the font's align correctly on wrapping.  To do that elements need to share the "typography" characteristics which means they need to inherit from the parent.  You could try specifying the typography in `<header>` and let h1 and p inherit from that

Comment: What typography characteristics are you referring to? The two elements have different `font-family`, `display`, `font-size`, and `top` (to set the baseline grid) attributes.

Comment: I'm refering to any css that has to do with font's and such....maybe this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/wybne/